# Spring application start error: sources must not be empty

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm following a Spring tutorial, and when I tried to start the spring application I got the following error:

> 2016-01-20 23:18:15.907  INFO 5271 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting SpringApplication
>   v1.3.1.RELEASE on  ...
>
> 2016-01-20 23:18:15.911  INFO 5271 --- [        main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set,
>   falling back to default profiles: default
>
> 2016-01-20 23:18:15.918 ERROR 5271 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication            : Application startup failed
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not be empty     at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:276)
>   ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:352)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.main(SpringApplication.java:1140)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]

What is this "Sources must not be empty" error?

I am using an Eclipse - Maven project for this tutorial project and I have updated the project. I have also cleaned and rebuilt but I still got this error.

Comment: Have  a look at the doRun method and see what the assertion is checking

Comment: Please add the relevant section of code, so people can offer more useful suggestions.

Comment: This can be caused by a dirty classpath with different versions of Spring libraries all over the place. Cleanup it and align it to the one and same Spring version with the correct versioned dependencies.

Comment: Please add the related code, especially your `SpringBootApplication` or `EnableAutoConfiguration` annotated class

Answer (score 26):

It turns out that I did not set the main class correctly in Eclipse - Debug, and Run configuration.

I set **org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication** as the main class.

The Main class should be pointing to my main class.

Answer (score 12):

Run the main class & not the project.

Comment: This worked for me, I tried executing the main Spring boot class and fixed

Comment: This worked for me. Scratched my head for an hour and finally, this worked.

Answer (score 10):

you must add at least one main config class as a source (see attached screenshots).

wrong:
[image]

right:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton. I forgot to add this. My main class just has a print of hello world. Silly me.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue recently, turned out I was running the wrong java class. I went to class where I have my @SpringBootApplication and right click -> run as java application. Hopefully that will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

add scanBasePackages="com.login" at main class thats all your code will work.

```
package com.login.example.LoginExample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.login")

public class LoginExampleApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LoginExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i solved it by changing the package of the main  class
to the root  package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

kindly check beans are created for your runner class or not by using `@Component` annotation on that class.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is instead of project name do right click on java file which contains main method. In our case java file which has @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in **SpringToolSuite** in *workspace window* **rightclick the project =>** **run as =>** **run configs =>** **main** tab(in popup) **=>** **project:** field **=>** browse and pickup the right project **=>** make sure in **Main class:** field there is you main class. Click  **Apply** and **Run**.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

- Make sure if you are not using Database in spring boot then don't use this
  dependency.
- I had same problem but when I removed this dependency it started worked.
  And also make sure you run project from your main class file

Answer (score -1):

You can change the package of the Main class by doing `Run>Run Configurations>Main Class>Search> Select "Spring Application`.
Then, If you get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not be empty` error. You can fix it by creating a new workspace.

Comment: I do not think it's a solution to the op's question.